# Logical error in printing boolean followed by integer in C language

Tags: c, printing, type-conversion

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=15;
    printf("\n%d%d%d",(x!=15),(x=20),(x>=15));
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, the desired output should be:
`0201`
But I am getting the output:
`1201`

What is wrong with my code? What it should be, for the desired operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The evaluation of arguments to a function are unsequenced, i.e. they can be evaluated in any particular order.  And because you're both reading and modifying `x` in a single expression without a sequence point in between them, you trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

You'll need to break up the printing into separate statements:

```
printf("%d\n",(x!=15));
printf("%d\n",(x=20));
printf("%d\n",(x>=15));
```

Comment: " they can be evaluated in any particular order." --> or even at the same time.